# web service method that takes an array of objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I need to write a web service that contains 2 methods to save a class and class details.
one method takes an object, the other method takes array of objects.
any advise?

Answer (score 0):

You may choose any type of service - WCF, .asmx, WebApi. All of them can serialize arrays of objects. But the object should be serializable.

WCF clients can generate strongly-typed proxy class:

```
MyServiceProxy client = new MyServiceProxy();
client.SavePersons(new List<Persons> { ... });
// list of persons will be transfered to server
```

WebApi service can deserialzie Json to Person class:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url: 'mysite.com/api/SavePersons',
    data: [{'Name':'Person1'},{'Name':'Person2'}]
});
```

Comment: could you provide me with an example?

Comment: Create WCF project in visual studio, run it. Then, create console application and add ServiceReference to you WCF service.